# Multiple options in Javascript replace function

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a program which changes amino acids back into DNA, so how do I put multiple options of DNA for each amino acid?

Here's what I have so far (changes each amino acid with one piece of DNA):

```
var v_codon = v_sequence.replace(/Phenylalanine/g,"UUU").replace(/Serine/g,"UCU").replace(/Tyrosine/g,"UAU").replace(/Cysteine/g,"UGU").replace(/Leucine/g,"UUA").replace(/Trytophan/g,"UGG").replace(/Proline/g,"CCU").replace(/Histidine/g,"CAU").replace(/Arginine/g,"CGU").replace(/Glutamine/g,"CAA").replace(/Isoleucine/g,"AUU").replace(/Threonine/g,"ACU").replace(/Asparagine/g,"AAU").replace(/Lysine/g,"AAA").replace(/Methionine/g,"AUG").replace(/Valine/g,"GUU").replace(/Aspartic Acid/g,"GAU").replace(/Alanine/g,"GCU").replace(/Glutamic Acid/g,"GAA").replace(/Glycine/g,"GGU");
```

Comment: What does "multiple options of DNA for each amino acid" mean?

Comment: do that multiple times

Comment: There are around 3 different sections of DNA for each amino acid and I need to put all options in my replace function so I can add an if statement to decide which section of DNA I should use.

Comment: You need to provide the algorithm in plain English with sample input and output. Also, format your code so it's easily readable. See [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The second argument to [*replace*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be a function that returns the value to use as the replacement.